# Vuejs 2 : How to make data lowercase

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lowercase

I trying to make some data to lowercase *(alway lowercase)*

I making and search input like :

```
<template id="search">
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="search">
        <li v-show="'hello'.includes(search) && search !== ''">Hello</li>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Vuejs :** (component)

```
Vue.component('search', {
    template : '#search',
    data: function(){return{
        search : '',
    }}
});
```

---

I tried `watch`, But I dont want input showing lowercase when typing

```
watch: {
    'search' : function(v) {
        this.search = v.toLowerCase().trim();
    }
}
```

**Demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/rgr2vnjp/

---

And I dont want to add `.toLowerCase()` on search list `v-show` like :

```
<li v-show="'hello'.includes(search.toLowerCase()) && search !== ''">Hello</li>
```

---

**Any trick?**, I searched and many tell just use `filter` but not exits on Vuejs 2

**Playground :** https://jsfiddle.net/zufo5mhq/ (Try to type **H**)

*PS: Good / better code I would like to know also, Thanks*

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Vue.js 2.0, computed properties can be used to replace filters:

```
computed: {
  searchInLowerCase() {
    return this.search.toLowerCase().trim();
  }
}
```

And now you can simply use `searchInLowerCase` in your template:

```
<li v-show="'hello'.includes(searchInLowerCase) && search !== ''">Hello</li>
```

Comment: Ahaaa! Thanks so much

Comment: Just a small enhancement for the trim(). You can put it directly to the template as:

v-model.trim="modelName"

Answer (score 16):

You could even do this

```
{{tag.title.toLowerCase().trim()}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should put all the logic in a `computed`, so you clearly separate the logic from the view/template:

```js
computed: {
  showHello() {
    const trimmedSearch = this.search.toLowerCase().trim()
    return 'hello'.includes(trimmedSearch) && this.search !== ''
  }
}
```

Then in your template:

```html
<li v-show="showHello">Hello</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the best way to integrate lowercase is to use vue filters:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ name | lowercase}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      name: 'I AM ROOT'
    })
    filters: {
      lowercase: function (value) {
        if (!value) return ''
        return (value.toString().toLowerCase())
      }
    }

  }
</script>
```