# filter a list of posts accepting lowerCase or Uppercase strings

Tags: vue.js, quasar

I intend to filter a list of posts by the title.

The logic is already implemented and works.

The problem that remains to be solved is to allow the filtering be done regardless of whether the strings contain upper or lower case letters.

**For example**: a string with the word *Today* should be able to be filtered in input by lowerCase, i.e., *today*

```
inputFilter:function(){
      var vm = this;
      return vm.posts.filter((post) => {
           return post.title.match(searchValue);
      });
 }
```

How to solve this?

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate to my eyes, but this question may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627497/vuejs-2-how-to-make-data-lowercase

Comment: Maybe transform every titles to lowercase : `return post.title.toLowerCase().match(searchValue);`

Comment: Thanks Meg, I couldn't get it to work with that solution

Comment: Thanks Pierre Said.this helps. I can filter by lowercase letters. but if I want to filter by uppercase it no longer works. For example the word Today: today works with your solution, but Today no longer works.

Comment: Try it like this: return post.title.toLowerCase().match(searchValue.toLowerCase());

Comment: Thanks Meg this works fine.If you want you can put in an answer to mark as resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either the toUpperCase() or toLowerCase() javascript functions :)

**Whichever function you use, be sure to apply it to both sides of the match statement.** Otherwise it will not match if the non transformed side includes a mix of upper case and lower case characters.

```
inputFilter:function() {
   var vm = this;
   return vm.posts.filter((post) => {
      return post.title.toUpperCase().match(searchValue.toUpperCase());
   });
}

inputFilter:function() {
   var vm = this;
   return vm.posts.filter((post) => {
      return post.title.toLowerCase().match(searchValue.toLowerCase());
   });
}
```

[MDN Web Docs - String.prototype.toUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)

[MDN Web Docs - String.prototype.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)